# Show that every orbit is unbounded.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following problem: Consider the system $x' = f(x)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, where $f$ is $C^1$-smooth. Suppose there is a function $E$ from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$, with $\dot{E}_f(x) = \nabla E(x)\cdot f(x) > 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Show that every orbit is unbounded.

I'd like to do this by assuming that the solution $x(t)$ is bounded, and showing that this leads to a contradiction. (I've been given a hint that this is a good way of solving the problem.)

So first I suppose that $x(t)$ stays (for all future times) in a ball of radius $R>0$. Then I let $E_0 = \min_{|x| \leq R} \dot{E}_f(x) > 0$. So $\frac{d}{dt}E(x(t)) \geq E_0$. This implies that $E(x(t)) \geq E_0 t + E(x(0))$.

I also have that $E(x(t)) \leq \max_{|x| \leq R}E(x)$. After this I am pretty much stuck.

Comment: I think your "This implies" is wrong.

Comment: It was definitely wrong. Fixed it, thanks. :)

Comment: What is a definition of $E_f$ ? $E_f=E$ ?

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it. Actually, $\tfrac d{dt}E(x(t))\ge E_0$ implies that
$$
E(x(t)) - E(x(s))\,\ge\,E_0(t-s)\quad\text{for all $t > s > 0$}.
$$
Now, consider the sequence $(x(n))_{n\in\mathbb N}$. Since it is bounded, it contains a convergent subsequence. In particular, for any $\varepsilon > 0$ we find $n > m$ such that $|x(n)-x(m)| < \varepsilon$. As $E$ is uniformly continuous on $B_R$, we even find $n > m$ such that $E(x(n))-E(x(m)) < \varepsilon$. Choosing $\varepsilon = E_0/2$, we get the contradiction
$$
E_0\,\le\,E_0(n-m)\,\le\,E(x(n))-E(x(m)) < \frac{E_0}2.
$$

Comment: How do I know that the function $E$ is uniformly continuous?

Comment: Every continuous function on a compact set is uniformly continuous. ;-)

Comment: Ah. Well, then I can follow your solution just fine, and I like your approach. What frustrates me however is that there is a hint for the problem stating that I should use the fact that $\frac{d}{dt} E(x) \geq E_0 t + E(x(0))$ to find a contradiction...

Comment: @RickS I see. But actually I see right now that this is also fine because $E$ is Lipschitz continuous on $B_R$. Hence, $E_0t\le|E(x(t))-E(x(0))|\le L|x(t)-x(0)|$, which is also a contradiction. Could you please check my answer? Thanks.

Comment: Why is that a contradiction though?

Comment: $E_0t\le L|x(t)-x(0)|\le L|x(t)| + L|x(0)|$, hence $L|x(t)|\ge E_0t - L|x(0)|$.

Answer (score 0):

How smooth is $E$?  If it is smooth enough, the following approach comes to mind.  Suppose a trajectory $\phi(t)$ of the dynamical system $x' = f(x)$ is bounded.  Then there exists a constant $c$ such that the level set $\{x: E(x) = c\}$ of $E$ is tangent to this trajectory at some point $t_{c}$.  Well, at that point, then,
$$
\phi'(t_{c}) = f(\phi(t_{c})
$$
lies in the tangent space of $\{x: E(x) = c\}$, hence is orthogonal to the gradient of $E$:
$$
\nabla E (\phi(t_{c})) \cdot f(\phi(t_{c}) = 0,
$$
contradicting the inequality given in your problem statement.